# Prevent screen from moving html5

Tags: html, screen

When I drag in the canvas of my web-app using my phone's browser , the whole screen will move. How do I stop that??

the code i've entered

```
<meta  charset="UTF-8" name="viewport"
 content="user-scalable=no,
          initial-scale=1.0,
          width=device-width,
          height=device-height,
          target-densitydpi=device-dpi"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have entered are two different meta tags. Change it to

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

Also bind select, touch and drag events like

```
element.onselectstart = function() { return false; };

element.ondragstart = function() { return false; };

element.ontouchstart = function(e) { e.preventDefault(); };
```

See it it helps.